# Угадай число (цикл while)

Tags: python

> Напишите программу-игру. Компьютер загадывает случайное число, пользователь
>   пытается его угадать. Пользователь вводит число до тех пор. пока не угадает или не
>   введет слово «Выход». Компьютер сравнивает число с введенным и сообщает
>   пользователю больше оно или меньше загаданного.

Мне не нравится, что первый вопрос по сути задается дважды. Что мне нужно исправить, чтобы сразу было сказано меньше число или больше задуманного?

```
from random import randint
N=randint(1,10)
K=int(input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 10:"))
while K!=N:
    K=int(input("Повторите попытку:"))
    if K<N:
        print("Ваше число меньше, чем задумал компьютер")
    elif K>N:
        print("Ваше число больше, чем задумал компьютер")
    else:
        print("Вы угадали")
print(K)
print(N)
```

Comment: Нужно исправить отступы.

Comment: @Эникейщик: Где именно?

Comment: В проверках. Они должны выполняться в цикле, а не после него.

Comment: @Эникейщик: Исправил. Но это я здесь (на форуме) только такую ошибку сделал. То есть вопрос актуален.

Comment: Задание лучше добавлять текстом.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, чтобы он полностью соответствовал заданию.

Comment: Ещё раз обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то так:

```
while K!=N:
    if K<N:
        print("Ваше число меньше, чем задумал компьютер")
    elif K>N:
        print("Ваше число больше, чем задумал компьютер")
    K=int(input("Повторите попытку:")
print("Вы угадали")
```

Comment: Не понял, как этот ответ связан с вопросом...

Comment: Теперь "вопрос не задается дважды" @Qwertiy

Comment: Блин.. Дошло... Я что-то про дублирование ввода в принципе думал, а не про то, что оно прям два раза подряд считывается и игнорит первый ввод.

Comment: Кстати, я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/cF50Qu

```
from random import randint

n = randint(1,10)

while 1:
  k = input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 10: ")

  if k == "Выход":
    print("В следующий раз повезёт!")
    break

  k = int(k)

  if k == n:
    print("Вы угадали")
    break

  print("Ваше число " + ("больше" if k > n else "меньше") + ", чем задумал компьютер")

print("Загаданным числом было: " + str(n))
```

Или так: https://ideone.com/qpdkwy

```
from random import randint

n = randint(1,10)
k = input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 10: ")

while 1:
  if k == "Выход":
    print("В следующий раз повезёт!")
    break

  k = int(k)

  if k == n:
    print("Вы угадали")
    break

  print("Ваше число " + ("больше" if k > n else "меньше") + ", чем задумал компьютер")

  k = input("Повторите попытку: ")

print("Загаданным числом было: " + str(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    from random import randint
    N=randint(1,10)
    K=int(input("Угадайте целое число от 1 до 10:"))
    while K!=N:
           if K<N:
              print("Ваше число меньше, чем задумал компьютер")
           elif K>N:
              print("Ваше число больше, чем задумал компьютер")
           K=int(input("Повторите попытку:"))
    print("Вы угадали")
    print(K)
    print(N)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]